# css, html, Image alignment

Tags: html, css

i Have 6 images and need to align them as:

```
 Img1        Img2

 Img3        Img4

 Img5        Img6
```

How should I? I am not able to do it properly.

```
<Image src = "" style = "margin-top: -10em; margin-left: -50em; float: left; width: 450px;" />

<Image src = "" style = "margin-top: -10em; margin-left: -10em; float: left; width: 450px;" />

<Image src = "" style = "margin-left: -120em; margin-top: -50em; float: left; width: 450px;" />

<Image src = "" style = "margin-left: -120em; margin-top: -50em; float: left; width: 450px;" />   

<Image src = "" style = "margin-left: -120em; margin-top: -50em; float: left; width: 450px;" />   

<Image src = "" style = "margin-left: -120em; margin-top: -50em; float: left; width: 450px;" />
```

The images are of equal size.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry to be anal about it but

**please please please don't use inline styles.**

**and PLEASE for the love of god, [don't use tables for non-tabular data](http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/everything.html)!**

Put them all in a list:

```
<ul>
  <li><img 1></li>
  <li><img 2></li>
  <li><img 3></li>
  <li><img 4></li>
  <li><img 5></li>
  <li><img 6></li>
</ul>
```

style them in a separate stylesheet:

```
ul li {
  float: left;
  width: 49%;
}
```

or something. Just specify the ul width if you dont want the list to take up the whole screen.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap a <div> - tag around them, like this:

```
<div style="width:yourimagewith x 2">
  <img src="1" />
  <img src="2" />
  <img src="3" />
  <img src="4" />
</div>
```

This solution doesn't give you all the fuss with styles and floats and so on.
Also, if you add new images, you don't have to add a new div tag after every two images, which seems not maintenance-friendly to me.

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick:

```
img { float:left; }
img:nth-child(odd) { clear:left; }
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/9k6ML/1/

Note, some backward browsers (IE...khm) don't support `:nth-child(odd)`.

Answer (score -2):

Simply float each image left and then after every second image put the following `<div style="clear: both;"></div>` that should fix your problem.

Comment: Would upvote but used them all for today :) Would be better with an external class in a .css file

Comment: I think to not use inline styles is rather common-sense ... he was after a quick demonstration not a guide on how to improve your markup structure.

Comment: @ZeSimon you should always teach best practises, if you don't people will believe what you are doing is okay for production code, Lead by example (not my downvote by the way man)

Comment: I didn't mean any disrespect I just believe as developers we have an obligation to produce good code all the time - even as examples :)

Comment: no no sorry on my behalf ... at first I took offense because I thought you down-voted just for sake of it, however you raise a valid point. I have worked on endless projects that have been frustrating because of these types of issues. I shall spread your legacy :).